# How to change the css style of the columns in the TableView in javafx successfully?

Tags: css, javafx, tableview

Hi guys I want to populate a `TableView` dynamically where its numbers of columns could be different in every execution of the application. Every column has to have a different background color. Every time the user select a value in the table, all cells with the same value will be selected, but once I change the style of the column the cells selected they are not highlighted any more. How can I solve this problem?

This is the fragment of code where I define the style for every columns:

```java
    ... ... ... ...
    int nPos = lttry.getPositionsSize();
    for(int i=1; i<= nPos; ++i) {
                
       String posName = data.getColumnPos(i).getName();
       TableColumn<Vector<String>,String> clnPos = new TableColumn<>(posName);
       String clmnId = "clmn"+posName; 
       clnPos.setId(clmnId);                    
        
       final int idxPos = i;
            
      clnPos.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Vector<String>, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<Vector<String>, String> p) {
                        return new SimpleStringProperty((p.getValue().get(idxPos)));
                    }
                });
      tblVwLttData.getColumns().add(clnPos);
            }
            
            ObservableList<Vector<String>> items =
                    FXCollections.<Vector<String>>observableArrayList();
    ... ... .... .... .....
```

The following picture shows the problem that I'm facing, the user has selected a cell with the value of 31 and all the cells with the same value has been selected, but these ones don't have the traditional blue color showing that those cells has been selected, only the text  color has changed to white.

[image: Sample of the problem]

the following is `css` file:

```css
    .table-view{    
        -fx-background-color: transparent;  
    }
    
    #clmnP1{
        -fx-background-color: #d0ae9caa;    
        -fx-backgrounds-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
    }
    
    #clmnP2{
        -fx-background-color: #f2d092aa;    
        -fx-backgrounds-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
    }
    
    #clmnP3{
        -fx-background-color: #92f2d2aa;    
        -fx-backgrounds-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
    }
    
    #clmnP4{
        -fx-background-color: #f2f292aa;    
        -fx-backgrounds-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
    }
    
    #clmnP5{
        -fx-background-color: #a987ccaa;    
        -fx-backgrounds-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
    }
    
    #clmnP6{
        -fx-background-color: #92d3f2aa;    
        -fx-backgrounds-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
    }
    
    #clmnP7{
        -fx-background-color: #92b3f2aa;    
        -fx-backgrounds-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
    }
```

I have tried several other solutions that have been proposed for similar problems with no success.

Comment: [mcve] please .. my guess is that the your css overrides all column/cell related rules (selected, focused,..) unconditionally

Comment: worksforme .. must be something else in your css/config